# align-self stretch not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I am practicing CSS flex boxes and everything is going good but when I tried to use align-self property all of its values work like flex-start , flex-end , center etc but the stretch one won't work here is the code

```css
#flexcontainer {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 450px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}
.flexitem {
  background: yellow;
  width: 48%;
  height: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 115px;
}
.one {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexitem one">1</div>
  <div class="flexitem two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once you specify a height on a flex item (e.g., `height: 115px`, like in your code), this overrides the `stretch` value on `align-items` or `align-self`. If you just want one column to stretch the full height, then instead of `align-self: stretch` use `height: 100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/hnx31czz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is fixed `height` on `.flexitem`'s  so you can overwrite with `height: auto`

```css
 #flexcontainer {
   border: 3px solid black;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height: 450px;
   justify-content: space-around;
   max-width: 500px;
   margin: 150px auto;
 }
 .flexitem {
   background: yellow;
   width: 48%;
   height: 115px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 115px;
 }
 .one {
   height: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexitem one">1</div>
  <div class="flexitem two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I thought I was going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Another posible solution.

```css
 #flexcontainer
 {
 border: 3px solid black;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height: 450px;
 justify-content: space-around;
 max-width : 500px;
 margin: 150px auto;
}
.flexitem
{
 background: yellow;
 width : 48%;
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 115px;
  
  /*Added*/
 align-self: flex-start;
}

.one {
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
    <div class="flexitem one">1</div> 
    <div class="flexitem two">2</div> 
   </div>
```